# Web, no carga imagen.png en "Iphone 6", q esta está dentro de un svg

Tags: javascript, html, svg, iphone, img

yo tengo creada una web, donde dentro de svg, tengo una imagen de W:8000px y H:4500px.

La tengo dentro de un svg.

El tema es que cuando abren la web desde ese celular en particular, no carga la imagen, si el svg y todos los elementos(polygon) que se crean automáticamente con js...

```
<div id="diver" class="zoom-svg-container" style="margin-bottom: 20px;">
                <svg id="usersvg" xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 500 280" height="100%" width="100%" version="1.1" preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMid slice" xmlns:cc="http://creativecommons.org/ns#"
                    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/">
                    <polyline id="polyline" style="fill:white;stroke:black;stroke-width:1"/>
                    <image id="imglote" xlink:href="resources/imagen.png" x="0" y="0" width="100%"></image>
                </svg>
                <div class="zoom-svg-zoom zoom-svg-zoom-in"> + </div>
                <div class="zoom-svg-zoom zoom-svg-zoom-rst"> = </div>
                <div class="zoom-svg-zoom zoom-svg-zoom-out"> - </div>
            </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La propiedad [`xlink:href`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/xlink:href) esta deprecada. En su lugar deberías usar [`href`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/href)

Es decir, deberías escribirlo así::

```
<image id="imglote" href="resources/imagen.png" x="0" y="0" width="100%"/>
```

#### Demo:

```html
<svg width="200" height="200" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"> 
  <image href="https://mdn.mozillademos.org/files/6457/mdn_logo_only_color.png" height="200" width="200"/>
</svg>
```